# UPS API .Net Add Web Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, wsdl, ups

Using the API package here: https://www.ups.com/gec/techdocs/pdf/Rates_Pkg_Gnd.zip

Added the reference to RateWS.wsdl by:

-Right click on website project -> Add Service Reference

-In the address field input: file://C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop\UPS API\RatingPACKAGE\PACKAGEWebServices\SCHEMA-WSDLs\RateWS.wsdl

Visual Studio added several reference files:

[image]

Using the Sample code provided in the API package, I copied the test code to my project.

The problem: The "RateService" class is not defined. Missing reference?

[image]

It appears the web reference was not added properly. The RateService class is unknown. Thanks for your help.

Comment: .. or it could be that the sample code is incorrect or out of date.

Comment: Anyone have a resource better than the one provided by UPS? The .NET API doesn't seem to work, or at least the examples they provide don't work.

Comment: @TomasBeblar I have same proble. Have you resolved it?

Comment: @Ranger No, I ended up using the EasyPost API. Not free, but works ok. https://www.easypost.com/

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that you are trying to add a Service Reference instead of a [Web Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628649.aspx):

> **To add a Web reference to a project**
>   In Solution Explorer, right-click the name of the project that you want to add > the service to, and then click Add Service Reference.
>   The Add Service Reference dialog box appears.
>   In the Add Service Reference dialog box, click the Advanced button.
>   The Service Reference Settings dialog box appears.
>   In the Service Reference Settings dialog box, click Add Web Reference.
>   The Add Web Reference dialog box appears.
>   I n the URL box, enter the URL of the Web service to use. If you do not know 
>   the URL, use the links in the browse pane to locate the Web service you want.

Answer (score 3):

UPS documentation is often out of sync with the code sample. You should modify your code like this:

```
FreightRatePortTypeClient Client = new FreightRatePortTypeClient();

....
....

FreightRateResponse resp = Client.ProcessFreightRate(upss, <your freight rate request object>);
```

This worked for me!