# Where is RateService in the current UPS schema

Tags: c#, .net-5, ups

I am trying to re-create the `Rate` code sample from the current *UPS Developer's Kit* on .Net 5. The code sample is based on .NET Framework 4.5.

I imported the `Rates_Pkg_Gnd\RatingPACKAGE\PACKAGEWebServices\SCHEMA-WSDLs\RateWS.wsdl` into a completely new .NET 5 Console project as a WCF Web Service (Visual Studio 2019).

I then copied the code from the code sample exactly line-by-line. Visual Studio added a reference to the imported Web Service. However, the very first line of code is not found in the new Web Service:

```
RateService rate = new RateService();
```

I contacted UPS Developer Support but "they do not help with coding". Has `RateService` been renamed or Is there a replacement in the new schema?

Comment: Please, check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363503/ups-api-net-add-web-reference. Probably, it is your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using WCF then it is called `RatePortTypeClient`.  Or if you choose to use a Web Reference it is called `RateService`.  You should also add a using [your reference name] to your code. Picture below shows `ServiceReference1` - as a WCF.  And `RateWebReference` as a Web Reference.

[image: Visual Studio Solution]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have the latest Rates_Pkg_Gnd (10/11/2021) from UPS. I have a using statement for my reference name. RateService still is not found. I am using a Web Reference.

Comment: is the reference listed under connected services or a folder called web reference?

Comment: This whole time I had thought I was adding a Web Reference, but I now know I was adding WCF. So, in VS2019 how do I add a Web Reference?

Comment: Hover mouse over references - click add service reference- a window will appear, then click advanced, bottom of new window you'll see add web reference.  Put your wsdl in c:\ root to make it easy to find.  You'll need the path to it.

Comment: I cannot see any advanced button

Comment: If you are using net core console app - im afraid you will have to use wcf.  Right-click project then add - service reference.  At bottom you will see wcf - click it and provide your path to wsdl.  I don't think you can add a web reference in net core.  This will add a connected service to your project.  Or you can use .net 4.5.